# build tensor flow graph in a loop

Tags: tensorflow

I have function that will define graph and do training; however, I want to run this training multiple time with different random seed.

```
for i in range(number_experiments):
    seed = np.random.randint(0, 2000)
    run(seed)
```

In my `run` method; it contains

```
def run(seed):
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype, [None,dimension], name='x')
    # Then construct computational graph
    # perform training
    # save log
    # so basically this function contains everything
```

However, the loop at beginning, only works for the first run; then when comes to second run experiments; it raise `ValueError:You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape`

I'm not sure why the first run is successful and the second run is failed.

Comment: In the line `seed = np.random.randint(0, 2000)` , you are creating a array of random integers where dtype=int32/int64. You need to cast the array into a dtype of np.float32.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal; thanks but I don't think this is the problem; I've cast to float32; I still have this problem